# Access local owncloud installation with a domain name

Tags: domain, port-forwarding, local-area-network, owncloud

I have owncloud installed on a local server at the office located at a buisness incubator and a web site with a domain name on a remote server.

Current installation:

- Domain: example.com that points to my remote server
- owncloud installation with local static ip 192.168.17.98:80
- incubator's ip/port 123.123.456.789:1234 forwarded to owncloud's local ip/port

I can access owncloud installation using incubarot's ip/port 123.123.456.789:1234 and a local ip 192.168.17.98:80

My goal is to be able to access owncloud using a sub domain **owncloud.example.com/**

Is this configuration possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My goal is to be able to access owncloud using a sub domain owncloud.example.com/
>
> Is this configuration possible?

Yes, mostly. All you need to do is go to add an A record for owncloud.example.com to the example.com DNS that points to 123.123.456.789 (sic).

Then you just access it as http(s)://owncloud.example.com:1234

Note that you still have to supply the port, like I said earlier - mostly.

If the business incubator can be persuaded to help, you may be able to get them to reverse proxy owncloud.example.com on port 80 which would remove the need for the port.